# Resize text area to fit all text on load jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I understand there has been a lot of discussion on this but I have yet to find a solution to fix my needs. Basically I need to autogrow a text area not when you type but on load. I am pulling in content from a database and dependant on the user's settings an overlay is produced over the text area, but upon doing this the text areas are not scrollable therefore I need to autosize these to show all the text.

I have tried scrollHeight but this is not working great as there are multiple text boxes on the screen

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `height: 100%`?

Comment: @desbest yes this wouldn't work as it is contained in a div

Comment: i lay-man approach can be to define an algorithm for the relation between text size and text area size , depeneding upon this , u can use $('#textAreaID').attr('size',calculatedSize); , a very undelightful but possible solution

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Try this

```
$("textarea").height( $("textarea")[0].scrollHeight );
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vsJRm/)

---

**UPDATE**

As a hack to make it work in older IE-s just add a really short delay before executing it

```
window.setTimeout( function() {
    $("textarea").height( $("textarea")[0].scrollHeight );
}, 1);​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vsJRm/4/)

**UPDATE FOR MULTIPLE TEXTAREAS**

```
$("textarea").each(function(textarea) {
    $(this).height( $(this)[0].scrollHeight );
});
```

Comment: This does not work in IE8 when you have multiple text areas. I have a large page with some heavy reliance on js for validation. Is there something in IE8 which may affect this?

Comment: This will also set the height of all text areas to the size of the first textarea in the array of html elements returned by jQuery.

Comment: @bruno This is an example what to use to solve the **real** issue. I'm pretty sure the OP won't have trouble to adapt the working example to his real situation which might include one or several textareas - the whole difference will be just a simple `each()`

Comment: This doesn't work on multiple textareas on the page - use Tormod Haugene's code instead - works GREAT

Comment: This is the kind of stuff ***why I love this place*** :D Ask Google the right question, as someone did in SO, and, presto, your snippet needs fulfilled!

Comment: @ZoltanToth Simply Excellent.

Comment: Seems like this only makes the textarea larger. If the text contained is smaller than the height of the textarea it does not appear to shrink it.

Comment: @JakeWilson You are right. The `scrollHeight` of textarea will be at least as high as the textarea itself, so when the textarea is taller than the content nothing will happen. The solution does not resize the textarea to fit _all_ content - short or tall - rather it applies to context of the question and fixes the issue of large text in a small textarea.

Comment: This seems to increase the height of the textarea indefinitely if you run it multiple times. But the solution is simple just remove the style height before you get scrollHeight. $('this').css('height', ''); It might help someone ... Isn't $this a typo and you meant $(this)?

Comment: if you delete text...the textarea doent shrink

Comment: @joe sure it doesn't - its' height was set during the onload event. If you want that functionality, then you have to implement it, e.g. set `height: auto` when an `onChange` event happens

Answer (score 42):

This worked for me; it loops through all "textarea" elements on page Ready, and set their height.

```
$(function () {
    $("textarea").each(function () {
        this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight+10)+'px';
    });
});
```

You can also combine it with an auto-expand function, to make it fully dynamic while writing as well:

```
function autoresize(textarea) {
    textarea.style.height = '0px';     //Reset height, so that it not only grows but also shrinks
    textarea.style.height = (textarea.scrollHeight+10) + 'px';    //Set new height
}
```

and call that from an "keyup" event or through jQuery:

```
$('.autosize').keyup(function () {
    autoresize(this);
});
```

Note how I am adding 10px to the scroll height: here you can adjust the amount of space you would like the bottom of the text area to give the user.

Hope that helps someone. :)

Edit: Changed answer according to @Mariannes comment.

Comment: Many thanks, this worked for me with a little modification. I set the 0px to 2em, and I'm not sure why you have "-10", I changed to "+10" so there's always a little whitespace below and it doesn't feel cramped.

Comment: Best answer for a well rounded and universal solution. Adjust -10 to desired padding of your textareas.

Answer (score 13):

you can use this. It works for me.

```js
$('#content').on('change keyup keydown paste cut', 'textarea', function () {
        $(this).height(0).height(this.scrollHeight);
    }).find('textarea').change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <textarea>How about it</textarea><br />
  <textarea>111111
222222
333333
444444
555555
666666</textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Not so good, because when textarea is too high (higher than screen) and I press any key at the bottom of the textarea, the screen scrolls up.

Comment: @IvanZ I solve the page scrolling problem. please try now.

Comment: @shamim reza, now texarea change its height every time when I press any key.

Answer (score 5):

You mentioned there are multiple textboxes. This code will set the height of each textarea according to its own contents.

```
$(document).ready( function( ) {

    $("textarea").each( function( i, el ) {
        $(el).height( el.scrollHeight );
    ​});

});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bruno/vsJRm/1/)

Comment: This does not work in IE8 when you have multiple text areas. I have a large page with some heavy reliance on js for validation. Is there something in IE8 which may affect this?

Comment: I am not sure why the downvote. IE8 compatibility was not mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you could use an editable div in HTML 5.

Reference : http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/editing.html#contenteditable

Answer (score 2):

This is an workaround.. and maybe an alternative solution:

```
 $('textarea').each(function(){
    var height = $('<div style="display:none; white-space:pre" id="my-hidden-div"></div>')
                 .html($(this).val())
                 .appendTo('body')
                 .height();     
   $(this).css('height',height + 'px');
   $('#my-hidden-div').remove();

});
```

You can see a demo here http://jsfiddle.net/gZ2cC/

Answer (score 0):

The solution of Tormod Haugene worked for me.

But my textareas where in an accordion and apparently it only worked if the textarea was visible on page load. The accordion items are triggered by clicking on elements with the class "title".

So I adapted the code Tormod Haugene to work inside accordion contents, that are set to display: none on page load.

Maybe this is useful for someone else in this situation:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.title', function () {
    jQuery("textarea").each(function () {
        this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight+10)+'px';
    });
});
```