# resize all textareas according to content inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

How can I resize all 'textarea' elements in my page according to the content inside and independent of one another?

So far I have tried using the following methods:
[Creating a textarea with auto-resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454202/creating-a-textarea-with-auto-resize) - which only resizes the first textarea
and [Resize text area to fit all text on load jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13085326/resize-text-area-to-fit-all-text-on-load-jquery) - which resizes all the textareas to the same height, rather than according to content.

Comment: Please add some code in your question.

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/. It applies for each textarea to increase the height automatically based on the content you have in the textarea. And you can search for auto grow text area jquery plugin in google. you get plenty of plugins that full fill your requirement