# Set textarea's autosize value as default

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use this function to autosize textarea:

```
$('textarea').each(function () {
    this.setAttribute('style', 'height:' + (this.scrollHeight) + 'px;overflow-y:hidden;');
    }).on('input', function () {
        this.style.height = 'auto';
        this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight) + 'px';
    });
```

I have this workflow: user goes to `page A`, fills textarea and saves it, then he closes `page A` and visit it again, textarea resizes only on `input`, but I need to resize it every time as user visits this page.

Comment: Take a look at thi solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/13085420/2990234

Comment: If you close and reopen the page, the javascript variable for the previous scrollHeight will be lost out of scope. If you dont have a way of saving the value to a backend, I'd recommend taking a look at browser localStorage for a get/set on the textarea height. Also, why not just set `this.style.height= 'auto'; this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight) + 'px';` outside of the `.on('input'` part of the code, in the `.each` part?

Comment: `.trigger('input')`?!

Comment: Thanks for replies, guys.
Unfortunately, I have no way to save such data to db. I tried to set values in `.each` part, didn't work. `.trigger('input')` doesn't work as well, tried it too.